# Convert from minutes since origin to date time for normal people ("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")?

Tags: r, date, netcdf, posixct

I'm working with a netcdf file which has its time units described as:
"minutes since 1850-01-16T14:06:00"

I'd like to have it in a more familiar date format for easier date matching and processing. The origin is given which is helpful, but I can't determine if I am using the wrong parsing formats or if the dates truly are not in line with the expectations I had.

I checked the help for `strptime()` and `as.POSIXct()` and haven't been able to figure out what format to use to parse this bizarre time structure.

```
# Example of the origin format and first 8 values
origin <- "1850-01-16T14:06:00"
dates_as_times <- c(52559874, 52602354, 52644834, 52688754, 
                    52732674, 52776594, 52820514, 52865154)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some packages for converting the netcdf files

```
library(RNetCDF)
library(lubridate)
out <- utcal.nc("minutes since 1850-01-16T14:06:00", dates_as_times)
out
#     year month day hour minute second
#[1,] 1949    12  23   12      0      0
#[2,] 1950     1  22    0      0      0
#[3,] 1950     2  20   12      0      0
#[4,] 1950     3  23    0      0      0
#[5,] 1950     4  22   12      0      0
#[6,] 1950     5  23    0      0      0
#[7,] 1950     6  22   12      0      0
#[8,] 1950     7  23   12      0      0
```

From the `matrix`, it can be easily converted to `Datetime` object with `ISOdatetime`

```
with(as.data.frame(out), ISOdatetime(year, month, day,
        hour, minute, second, tz = 'GMT'))
#[1] "1949-12-23 12:00:00 GMT" "1950-01-22 00:00:00 GMT" "1950-02-20 12:00:00 GMT" "1950-03-23 00:00:00 GMT"
#[5] "1950-04-22 12:00:00 GMT" "1950-05-23 00:00:00 GMT" "1950-06-22 12:00:00 GMT" "1950-07-23 12:00:00 GMT"
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(ncdf.tools)
convertDateNcdf2R(dates_as_times, origin = ymd_hms(origin))
```

---

Or we could multiply with 60

```
as_datetime(dates_as_times * 60, origin = ymd_hms(origin))
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, and am now unsure if this is an R/netcdf issue or a posixct issue that might be a local issue. 

Here is some more information on the data source. I know that the output of this conversion should result in  ~1 month intervals due to the data source itself.

When reading it in python using xarray the dates are: 
1950-01-16 12:00:00, 1950-02-15 00:00:00, etc.

So that is kind of my expected output. These two methods return:
"1851-09-16 22:03:54 UTC",  "1851-09-17 09:51:54 UTC"

Comment: @AdamKemberling If you can show the expected output, it would be great.  Is the python output correct

Comment: @AdamKemberling I get similar output if I multiply by 60 `as_datetime(dates_as_times * 60, origin = ymd_hms(origin))`

Comment: The python output is consistent with the rest of the files in the larger collection so I believe it to be correct. Expected output for the first 5 values would be: 1950-01-16 12:00:00, 1950-02-15 00:00:00, 1950-03-16 12:00:00, 1950-04-16 00:00:00, 1950-05-16 12:00:00. This file and one other of the collection of 50 read in with this "minutes since" format, the others coming in as expected.

Comment: @AdamKemberling There is also an option with `library(ncdf.tools);convertDateNcdf2R(dates_as_times, origin = ymd_hms(origin))`

Comment: Thank you for the *60 solution. Would that imply that the units from nc_attget() are labeled incorrectly? Hours, but labeled as minutes.

Comment: @AdamKemberling I updated with `ISOdatetime` to get a datetime class

Comment: I am only getting the expected (matches xarray) results using the `as_datetime(dates_as_times * 60, origin = ymd_hms(origin))` approaches. Which leads me to believe that the metadata is incorrect, and its actually "hours" since the origin.

Comment: @AdamKemberling Changing the `hours since` is giving me large values.  So something is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229223/discussion-between-adam-kemberling-and-akrun).